# Centre a view in its parent, when in landscape

Tags: objective-c

I've search and found a few questions about this, but none containing an answer that worked for me.

This code centres a subview in the current view, if the device is in portrait, but not if it's landscape. How do I make the centring work in landscape?

```
UIView *redView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
redView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
redView.center = [self.view convertPoint:self.view.center fromView:self.view.superview];
[self.view addSubview:redView];
```

Comment: Use autoresizingMask to center it.

Comment: As shown in the long discussion below, the code above wasn't my problem. It was because I was adding the subview before the parent view was loaded. Although the suggested centering code may be better in some cases, both it and my original code actually centre the view, when done in the right place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather try using

```
 redView.center = [self.view convertPoint:self.view.center fromView:nil];
```

Works for me.

Note from the docs:

> The view with point in its coordinate system. If view is nil, this
>   method instead converts from window base coordinates. Otherwise, both
>   view and the receiver must belong to the same UIWindow object

(should be called in viewDidAppear, not in viewDidLoad)

Comment: Thanks, but that gives me the exact same result. Centred in portrait, off-centre in landscape.
Nothing else funky going on, either. I set up a fresh project, put only that code into viewDidLoad, and ran it. No good.

Comment: I tried in a sample app myself just now and it works fine. Try the following: Put your device/simulator in Landscape and launch your app. If it still doesn't work than you have a different problem to my solution. (When the app is launched in Portrait, and it gets rotated to Landscape the center point needs to be recalculated.)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what to say. I've run it in both the device and simulator, with each in landscape at launch, and it's off centre. And I've put no other code in the app, so...I don't know.

Comment: I presume its an iPhone app you are working on? It seems like the original orientation is defaulted to portrait. I tested with an iPad app. Using autoresizing masks might help you with your problem as suggested by @Armaan: "redView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;"

Comment: Alternatively implement the orientation delegate method: "
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    redView.center = [self.view convertPoint:self.view.center fromView:self.view.superview];
}
"

Comment: No, it's iPad, so I'd love to know why my results are different to yours.
Did we both do the exact same thing? New single-view application, my code in viewDidLoad for the viewController (except with your centering line, rather than mine)?

Autoresizing and rotation delegates might work for this simple example, but I'd rather work it out with basic positioning, because I'm sure there will be instances where I'll need to do it this way.

Comment: Ok, so initially I tested on an existing iPad application of mine, and it worked fine. I then created a new iPhone application, but the orientation was forced to Portrait (Can't quite figure out now why this was happening.). I created a new clean iPad application and experienced your problem. I should have noticed earlier that your problem originates from the fact that the center of the view is set in viewDidLoad. (viewDidLoad is called before the window transform is applied). Try placing your code in viewDidAppear and it should work fine.